# MVVMCross, WPF, XAML "Unable to resolve the binding creator - have you initialized Windows Binding"

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding, mvvmcross

I am trying to make a simple WPF application using MVVMCross that has two views and two view models.  All I want to happen is for a button on the initial view to open the second view, using the `MvvmCross.BindingEx.Wpf` nuget package. Here is the first tag in my XAML code:

```
<views:MvxWpfView 
         x:Class="FirstMVVMProject.WPF.Views.FirstView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:views="clr-namespace:Cirrious.MvvmCross.Wpf.Views;assembly=Cirrious.MvvmCross.Wpf"
         xmlns:mvx="clr-namespace:mvx;assembly=Cirrious.MvvmCross.BindingEx.Wpf"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" >
```

And here is the button:

`<Button Width="50" Height="50" mvx:Bi.nd="Command GoCommand"/>`

And here is my viewmodel class:

```
namespace FirstMVVMProject.Core.ViewModels{
using System.Windows.Input;

using Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels;

public class FirstViewModel : MvxViewModel
{      
        private MvxCommand _goCommand;
        public ICommand GoCommand
        {
            get
            {
                _goCommand = _goCommand ?? new MvxCommand(GoToSecond);
                return _goCommand;
            }
        }

        private void GoToSecond()
        {
            base.ShowViewModel<SecondViewModel>();
        }
}
}
```

When I try to run the program, I get an `XamlParseException` on the line where this button is, and in the inner exception part of the exception snapshot, it says

> Unable to resolve the binding creator - have you initialized Windows Binding.

I even have no idea how to approach this. Does any one know what could be the issue and how I can resolve it?

Comment: This seems to be wrong: `mvx:Bi.nd`
Also would it be possible for you to create a sample code and replicate the issue

Comment: That is the syntax for Mvvmcross in xaml, I've seen it used elsewhere.  And I don't think so, the project and mvvmcross requires a lot of background stuff that I wouldn't be able to post here.

Comment: Have you tried following "BindingEx - Tibet and Rio in Xaml" in https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/Databinding

Comment: That worked! I had not put `InitializeLastChance()` in `Setup.cs`. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As directed by Stuart, I checked out [this document](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/Databinding), which described Tibet and Rio in Xaml.  I was missing this bit of code in my `Setup.cs` class.

```
protected override void InitializeLastChance()
{
    base.InitializeLastChance();

    var builder = new MvxWindowsBindingBuilder();
    builder.DoRegistration();        
}
```

After I pasted that in, everything worked fine. Thanks!